# Inkscape + Android Studio: Which one is the right format to export for compatibility?

Tags: inkscape, svg, android

So I was usually creating svg data with inkscape for my Android Projects but recently the import and conversion doesn't work anymore.

I compared my old assets with the new ones and seen that the old ones only use the moveTo tag in the path data. The newer ones use Arc and others ones which seems to be the reason.

Can I force Inkscape to only use moveTo in the path when saving?